# Calculating $E[x]$ from even probability density function $f_{XY}$

Tags: calculus, probability, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

I'm a new user on this site, and I have a question about calculus and probability. I want to prove that

$E[x] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} xf_{XY}(x; y)dxdy = 0$

when $E[x]$ is the expected value of the random variable $X$, and $f_{XY}(x; y)$ is an even probability density function, such that $f_{XY}(-x; -y) = f_{XY}(x; y)$, of the couples of random variables $(X; Y)$.

I have no idea how to prove that.
Can anyone help me ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $f_{XY}(x,y)=f_{XY}(-x,-y)$ for all $x,y$. Let's use two new variables $u=-x$ and $v=-y$. With this the Jacobian=$1$ and

$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xf_{XY}(x,y)dxdy=\int_{+\infty}^{-\infty}\int_{+\infty}^{-\infty}(-u)f_{XY}(u,v)dudv=-\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}uf_{XY}(u,v)dudv$.

So $$E[X]=-E[X]=0.$$

Comment: I'm sorry zoli, I have a little doubt. Why $\int_{x=-u=+\infty}^{-\infty}\int_{v=-y=+\infty}^{-\infty}(-u)f_{XY}(u,v)dudv=-\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}uf_{XY}(u,v)dudv$ ?

Comment: @pwm: Do in three steps. (1) Change $(-u)$ to $u$ and then (2) turn the inner integral up side down.The sign changes will cancel out. (3) Then change the outer integral. Then the sign will change again.

Comment: Okay, it's fine!